# Is "result in" a separable phrasal verb?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I know *result in" is not separable the way *switch on* (something), "put on" (some piece of clothes), to name just a few, are. However I wonder if I can compose a sentence using "result in" like the following?

> If human resources lack the skills and knowledge required for working in a varying environment, it could undoubtedly be said that any other endeavor and expense will not result but in a loss.

For me, the reason for separating *result+in* was only aesthetics. On grammatical integrity of my sentence, however, I am not sure.

Comment: @MaulikV It is quite clear that the OP asserts authorship of the sentence himself.

Comment: As a native speaker I can tell you that it just doesn't seem to parse properly for me - it would normally be phrased either "...will result in nothing but a loss." or "...will not result in anything other than a loss."

Comment: @bruisedreed ah I missed it. The sentence seemed off to me and that's the reason I asked for the source

Answer (score 2):

In your examples:

> switch on (something)
>   put on (some piece of clothes)

these are used a transitive verbs, so the object can split them.

> switch (something) on
>   put (some piece of clothing) on

But *result* is an intransitive verb, so there is no object.

In this example:

> That will **result in** sending two notices **separately**.
>     That will **result separately in** sending two notices.

So you can split it, but not as in your example. When you can split it, I think you can usually turn it around as in the above examples. I would not naturally say say:

> any other endeavor and expense will not result in **but** a loss.

Comment: You mean *result in* is not a phrasal verb?

Comment: I reconsidered. It is really about how it splits. Please check my edits.